# Live Reload não funcionando no Expo

Tags: android, react-native, mac, expo, genymotion

Ao emular um app feito com expo no *Genymotion*, o *live reload* do Expo não funciona, o menu de opções nem mesmo é aberto (seja utilizando a ação de chacoalhar o smartphone ou apertando no botão para isso). Dentre os sistemas que já utilizei ***Expo + genymotion*** para emular, não tinha acontecido isso, só no Mac OS deu problema.
**Soluções que já tentei:**

- Instalar watchman
- Executar em um dispositivo físico (nem mesmo lá o menu abre)
- "Limpar" a node_modules a apagando e reinstalando
- Atualizar expo-cli

Nenhuma dessas opções funcionaram.

Comment: está rodando o projeto á partir do xcode?

Comment: Não, mas já resolvi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por mais vergonhoso e idiota que isso seja, eu achei a solução.
Estava no **modo de produção**, assim não havia live ou hot reload.